# htaccess redirect for not existing files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect on my website if a file does not exsist as .php file but it does as .html file. For exmaple:

If page.php does not exsist i want to redirect to page.html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /default.php [L]
```

So far i managed to redirect to default.php if any file does not exsist. How can i redirect to the html file if one exsists and how do i limit this on redirection on php files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always been a fan of explicit and transparent rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```